# Checking if an RDD(K,V) V is contains in another Rdd(K,V) V

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have two RDD(K,V),in spark it is not allow two map nesting。

```
val x = sc.parallelize(List((1,"abc"),(2,"efg"))）
val y = sc.parallelize(List((1,"ab"),(2,"ef"), (3,"tag"))
```

I want check "abc" contains "ab", if the RDD is large or not.

Comment: can you update the question with the desired output that you are looking for.

Comment: thanks , I want know "abc" is contains "ab",the out put like (abc, efg)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to select a value from **RDD x** when it's substring is present in the **RDD y** then this code should work.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val x = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1, "abc"), (2, "efg")))
  val y = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List((1, "ab"), (2, "ef"), (3, "tag")))

  // This RDD is filtered. That is we are selecting elements from x only if the substring of the value is present in
  // the RDD y.
  val filteredRDD = filterRDD(x, y)
  // Now we map the filteredRDD to our result list
  val resultArray = filteredRDD.map(x => x._2).collect()
}

def filterRDD(x: RDD[(Int, String)], y: RDD[(Int, String)]): RDD[(Int, String)] = {
  // Broadcasting the y RDD to all spark nodes, since we are collecting this before hand.
  // The reason we are collecting the y RDD is to avoid call collect in the filter logic
  val y_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(y.collect.toSet)
  x.filter(m => {
    y_bc.value.exists(n => m._2.contains(n._2))
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks，use broadcast when the data is small。